# Update values in dictionary with values in another list

Tags: python

I want to update my `Original_dict` so that its values are updated using the names provided in the `Required_list`:

```
Original_dict= {"key1": "John", "key2": "Mary", "key3": "Karen"}
Required_list= ["Aoron", "Ketty", "Norman"]
```

Expected Output:

```
Original_dict= {"key1": "Aoron", "key2": "Ketty", "key3": "Norman"}
```

This is what I have tried but it throws an error, please help me with this code:

```
Original_dict= {"key1": "John", "key2": "Mary", "key3": "Karen"}
Required_list= ["Aoron", "Ketty", "Norman"]

for i in range(0,len(Original_dict)):
    Original_dict[i] = Required_list(i)

print(Original_dict)
```

Comment: What is your error

Comment: `new_dict = dict(zip(Original_dict.keys(), Required_list))`

Comment: Your `Original_dict`'s keys are all strings, so using an integer to update its contents via `Original_dict[i]` won't work. What is the correspondence between the elements in the `Required_list` and the key strings in `Original_dict`?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

With zip --

```
Original_dict= {"key1": "John", "key2": "Mary", "key3": "Karen"}
Required_list= ["Aoron", "Ketty", "Norman"]

new_dict  = dict(zip(Original_dict,Required_list))
```